# Accessing a ListView delegate's text from C++

Tags: c++, qt, listview, location, qml

I want to find a waypoint path by two coordinates. In order to do this I need to access a QML property from C++. How can I access the property below?

```
import QtLocation 5.6
import QtPositioning 5.6
import QtQml 2.2
Item {
    Plugin
    {
        id:osmPlugin
        name:"osm"
    }

    RouteModel
    {
        id: routeModel
        plugin: osmPlugin
        autoUpdate: true
        query: aQuery
    }
    RouteQuery
    {
        id: aQuery

    }

    property  list<string> rectx

    Repeater
    {
        id: listview
        model: routeModel.status == RouteModel.Ready ? routeModel.get(0).segments : null
        visible: model ? true : false
        delegate: Row {
            property bool hasManeuver : modelData.maneuver && modelData.maneuver.valid
            property RouteSegment routeSegment: modelData

            Text
            {
                id:tt2
                text: routeSegment.path // I need to access this value              
            }

        }   

    }

    Location
    {
        id:l1
        coordinate
        {
            latitude:0.0
            longitude:0.0
        }
    }
    Location
    {
        id:l2
        coordinate
        {

            latitude:0.0
            longitude:0.0
        }
    }

    property string someString
    property string someString1
    property string lang
    property string lang1


    function myQmlFunction(coord)                                         

    {
        someString=coord
        someString1=coord
        lang= someString.substring(0,6)
        lang1= someString1.substring(10,16)
        l1.coordinate.longitude = lang
        l1.coordinate.latitude= lang1
        l2.coordinate.longitude = lang
        l2.coordinate.latitude= lang1
        aQuery.addWaypoint(l1.coordinate,l2.coordinate)
        aQuery.travelModes=RouteQuery.CarTravel
        aQuery.routeOptimizations=RouteQuery.ShortestRoute
        routeModel.update()
        console.log("Got message:",)
        return "some return value"
    }

}
```

Comment: @Yoann, removing the OP's question from the post makes this come off as kinda demanding and rude (not that it was greatly phrased to begin with).

Comment: Are you sure you need to access it from C++? Doing so is usually a bad design decision. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: because my database  ,  program and ui widgets  in c++ . so ı chose this way but ı think move database in qml

Answer (score 0):

I used this method to pass data from QML to C++

First you need to create a class (MyClass) and connect it to Qml, for that see  [this tuto on youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7cH7DXrzxWU)

Next, for me I used `MouseArea` to transmit data to c++ MyFunction in MyClass:

```
delegate: Rectangle {
    width: parent.width
    Text {
        id: txt
        text: modelData
        anchors.centerIn: parent
    }
    MouseArea {
        anchors.fill: parent
        onClicked: {
            listView.currentIndex = index
            label.text = MyClass.MyFunction(txt.text)
        }
    }
}
```

if you don't want to use `MouseArea` use `Component.onCompleted` in `Text` and then call `MyClass.MyFunction(txt.text)`